# Does yii2 have persistent connection options?

Tags: yii2, mariadb, keep-alive, persistent-connection

I can't find documentation about Yii2 persistent connection.

I have problems with Yii2 behavior. It always opens the connection and closes it after executing the query. I think creating a persistent connection is the answer to my problems.

How to do that?

Answer (score 3):

See the following github [issue](https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/1363):

```
    'db' => array(
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'tablePrefix' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'attributes'=>[
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
        ]
    ),
```